# Conditionally formatting cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format, conditional-statements

I am conditionally formatting a range of cells. I want to do greater than and less than another cell value. I have found this code online that lets me do that but I was wondering if there is a way to skip formatting if the condition cell is blank.

Example: I want to highlight "G14" red if the value is greater than "D14"+"E14". Vise versa for minus. If the value of "E14" is blank it still make s it red because it is acting as if it is zero.

Here is my code:

```
'Format Measured
 Dim rg As Range
 Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
 Set rg = Range("G14", Range("G14").End(xlDown))

'clear any existing conditional formatting
rg.FormatConditions.Delete

'define the rule for each conditional format
Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=$D14+$E14+$H14")
Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, "=$D14-$F14")

'define the format applied for each conditional format
With cond1
.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
.Font.Color = vbRed
End With

With cond2
.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
.Font.Color = vbRed
End With
```

Comment: Hm, maybe different routes here. I'm thinking along the lines of `SpecialCells` or an adaptation of your formula to include `"<>"""`

Comment: So should the conditional formatting check if either `D14` or `E14` is blank, or just `E14`?

Comment: Just E14. The way I have my spreadsheet is I have a measurement in D14 and a tolerance in E14 and F14. Some measurements do not have tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

Proposing the alternate solution to use a formula:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
    Set rg = Range("G14", Range("G14").End(xlDown))

    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete

    'define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=AND($G14>$D14+$E14,$E14<>"""")")
    Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=AND($G14<$D14-$E14,$E14<>"""")")

    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With

    With cond2
        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that if the format is the same for each rule, then you could combine the two into one.

Comment: This worked for G14. is there a way to do the whole selection or loop this?

Comment: I can't replicate that - works for the entire range for me. How did you implement it?

Comment: Unless OP needs `xlUp` (meaning maybe `G15` was empty?), but for me it also works =)

Comment: I copied and pasted the new code into my original code. It worked for the first 2 cells but not the rest of the cells where the condition was blank. the rest of the spreadsheet formats fine.

Comment: What is the range that the conditional formatting is applied to? You can see it under *Conditional Formatting* > *Manage Rules*.

Comment: It is being applied to G14-G1443. None of that range is blank. It is formatting correctly for the whole range. It is just not skipping if cells E or F is blank.

Comment: Should the conditional formatting also check if F is blank then? You did not stipulate that.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry... Would I copy the code and specify for F as well? F is actually cond2. i just realized that

Comment: It is only applying the formula above to G14. The rest of the cells are $G16>$D16+$E16 and  $G16<$D16-$F16

Comment: This is probably different from what I'm trying to do but each format needs to be specific for that row. All of the cells are in the same position but have different values (i.e. D and F). Each cell has a different value. Right now everything is being tied to cells "D14" and "F14"

Comment: Did you by accident add dollar signs `$` before the `14`?

Comment: No. after digging a little deeper it is applying the formula in the code to row 14 and applying the basic formula for the rest of the sheet referencing row 17.

Comment: Do yo think I need to set the row number as a variable and do them one at a time with a loop?

Comment: No. You need relative references - no `$` before the 14. Excel updates the 14 to 15, 16, 17, etc. for each successive row when applying conditional formatting.

Comment: For some reason it stop after row 15 and references all other rows to 15. Could my Dim rg be constraining it?

Comment: I discovered I had .select for my Dim rg. i took that away and now the formula applies to all cells but it is the same formula referencing row 14

Comment: Is there a way to change the applies to option? My Dim rg isnt allowing the format to go down i think. Sorry for all of the comments.... Haha

Comment: @BrandonCampbell - at this point I think you should ask a new question, with the exact code you're trying and the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this multiple ways, but as per my comment, for example:

```
Set rg = Range("D14", Range("G14").End(xlDown))
Set rg = Intersect(rg.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Rows.EntireRow, Range("G:G"))
```

I would also consider to be explicit about your range object, consider refering to a Sheet object.

Btw, if you also want to avoid if `E14` is blank, you can extend the `Intersect`:

```
Set rg = Intersect(rg.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Rows.EntireRow, rg.Columns(2).SpecialCells(2).Rows.EntireRow, Range("G:G"))
```

Obviously, another answer could be on how you could use a formula as a condition which checks if cells are '<>""`

Comment: I am really new to VBA. Do you know of a formula to use?

Comment: @brandoncampbell, check out the other answer for that alternative =)